# Show horizontal scollbar only if screen width falls below 1024px

Tags: html, css

How can I show scroll bars horizontally only if the screen resolution falls below 1024px width:

**HTML**

```
<div id="divHome" class="divHome">
    <section id="headerSection" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="headerTitle">Scan Equipment</div>
    </section>
    <section id="ScanEquipmentSection" class="container-fluid row">
    </section>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media (orientation: landscape) and (min-width: 1024) {
  #divHome {
    width: auto;
    height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just set a min-width on your wrapper? Media queries probably aren't necessary.

Comment: `body { min-width: 1024px; }` and your website will always be at least 1024px wide. If the screen is less then 1024px wide, the body will enforce thw width with a horizontal scrollbar. As isherwood alread stated, media queries are not necessary for it.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put `px` after your `1024` and it should be `max-width` not `min-width`

```css
@media (orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #divHome {
    width: auto;
    height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="divHome" class="divHome">
    <section id="headerSection" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="headerTitle">Scan Equipment</div>
    </section>
    <section id="ScanEquipmentSection" class="container-fluid row">
    </section>
</div>
```